# jinja2 include files based of of dict variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to create a templated file with jinja2 and ansible

currently i have a dict with multiple entries  e.g:

```
internal_sites:
  - {name: "site1" ,url: "site1.example.com" }
  - {name: "site2" ,url: "site2.example.com" }
  - {name: "site3" ,url: "site3.example.com" }
  - {name: "site4" ,url: "site4.example.com" }
```

I have a a directory that has multiple files eached also named after the value in 'name'

```
├── templates
│   ├── base.cfg.j2
│   └── services
│       ├── internal
│       │   ├── site1.txt
│       │   ├── site2.txt
│       │   ├── site3.txt
│       │   ├── site4.txt
```

Within base.cfg.j2 im trying to loop over each item in internal_sites which generates the appropriate config i require and at the same time im trying to include the content of the text files.

the instructions i have are as follows:

```
{% for site in internal_sites %}
  acl {{ site.name }} hdr(host) -i {{ site.url }}
  use_backend {{ site.name }} if {{ site.name }}

  backend {{ site.name}}
    {% include "templates/services/internal/"{{lookup('vars', site.name)}} %}

{% endfor %}
```

however whenever i run my ansible i get the following error;

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got '{'. String: \n{% for site in internal_sites %}\n  acl {{ site.name }} hdr(host) -i {{ site.url }}\n  use_backend {{ site.name }} if {{ site.name }}\n\n  backend {{ site.name}}\n    {% include \"templates/services/internal/\"{{lookup('vars', site.name)}} %}\n\n{% endfor %}\n"}
```

i have also tried with the following

```
{% for site in internal_sites %}

  {% set fileloc = 'templates/services/internal/' + site.name %}
  acl {{ site.name }} hdr(host) -i {{ site.url }}
  use_backend {{ site.name }} if {{ site.name }}

  backend {{ site.name}}
    {% include {{fileloc}} %}

{% endfor %}
```

I'm aware this is likely wrong but could anyone shed some guidance on the most appropriate way to do this?

expected output

```
  acl site1 hdr(host) -i site1.example.com
  use_backend site1 if site1

  backend site1
    contents of site1.txt
    are included
    here
```

Comment: Mustaches do not stack; I presume you want `{% include "templates/services/internal/" + site.name + ".txt" %}` or, if you prefer your 2nd example, `{% include fileloc + ".txt" %}`

Comment: Yep thats done the Trick! 

thanks @mdaniel :) i wasnt aware mustaches dont stack!